# How to create multiple pivot tables for the same two models in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have to models User & Article

User can like Article &
User can bookmark article

if i create a pivot than it will be same for both user_article pivot

Can any one help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define another relationship in these models and add [custom pivot table name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

```
public function anotherRelationship()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article', 'another_pivot_table_name');
}
```